why doesn't selenium webdriver work on the server?
I want to create a webscraping bot using selenium, and if i run the code on my mac it works, but if i run it from a server using github it gives me an error.
this is the code:
from selenium import webdriver

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chromeOptions.add_argument("ignore-certificate-errors")
chromeOptions.add_argument('--headless=chrome')
wbe = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)

This is the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
wbe = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 86, in start
raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home


you didn't read 'Wrong permissions' ?

The error is quite literally telling you why it doesn't work, and you can fairly easily copy that error, paste it into a web search, and find out how to fix it. E.g. you might find posts like Selenium on MAC, Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions.

but if i run it local in my mac it work (without chromedriver), the problem is that if i run it from a server (ubuntu) it doesn't work

You can try/catch the error and set permissions and re-initialize if this exception is caught.
